# trying to make a simple shakes and fidget like game. But the code either gives out an error or types "none"

Tags: python

Hopefully you don't mind the foreign language in prints.
Also I started python last week so sorry if the code is bad and unpractical.

Okay so what im trying to do is have a player health and player damage multiplied by a random number between 1-10 and then subtract the result from the enemy health (the easy health variable) and then do the same the other way around (playerhealth-easydamage*random)
And then if the enemy's or players health reaches 0 a message about the winner gets printed out. I haven't gotten to that part yet. My problem is i only either got File stdin syntax error or the out put is literally "None"

```
def fightgame():
    Player_Health=150
    Player_Damage=7
    Easy_Health=120
    Easy_Damage=5
    for _ in range(5):
        x= random.randint(1,10)
        def Easy_PT():
            Pdamage = x * Player_Damage
            Easy_Health - Pdamage
            if Easy_Health != 0: 
                print ("Vyhral si.")
            else:
                print ("Boss má " +Easy_Health+ "životov.")
        def Easy_FT():
            Edamage = x * Easy_Damage
            Player_Health - Edamage
            if Player_Health != 0:
                print ("Prehral si.")
            else:
                print ("Máš " +Player_Health+ "životov.")
print(fightgame())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fightgame()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your post may get flagged as a bad questions, but dont mind it for now...

Its not easy to completly understand your question, but this is what I've changed to make it run how I think you want it to work.

It printed None because you were printing a function that doesnt return anything.
Printing works everywhere, so you can do it where ever you want.
[Here you can read more about functions and print and return.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp)

```
import random


def fightgame():
    Player_Health = 150
    Player_Damage = 7
    Easy_Health = 120
    Easy_Damage = 5
    for _ in range(5):
        x = random.randint(1, 10)

        Pdamage = x * Player_Damage
        Easy_Health -= x * Pdamage
        if Easy_Health <= 0:
            print("Vyhral si.")
        else:
            print("Boss má " + str(Easy_Health) + " životov.")

        Edamage = x * Easy_Damage
        Player_Health -= Edamage
        if Player_Health <= 0:
            print("Prehral si.")
        else:
            print("Máš " + str(Player_Health) + " životov.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fightgame()
```

Have fun trying it out.

Comment: thank you, u kind of understood what i meant, finally got the code to do what i wanted after a little tweaking, no idea how to upload the code in the comment so im not gonna paste it here. Thank you for your help tho it helped a lot